# setTimeout not working after getting redirected to another website

Tags: jquery, redirect

I have this in `localhost:8080`:

```
"<form action='http://localhost:3000/login#localhost:8080' method='POST''>" +
                    "<input type='email' name='username' label='Username'>Username" +
                    "<input type='password' name='password' label='Password'>Password<br>" +
                    "<input type='submit' value='Login'>" +
                    "</form>"
```

What I want is to redirect back to `localhost:8080` after logging in, but it is not working for now. But this is not the issue at the moment, though it would be great to find similar way of redirecting. Anyway, here's my jQuery:

```
        $('form').submit(function(){
            alert('test');
            setTimeout(function(){
                alert('testagain');
            }, 3000);
        });
```

`alert('test')` is working, but after I am redirected to `localhost:3000`, `alert('testagain')` is not working. The plan is to put here a code that redirects me back to `localhost:8080`, e.g. `window.location`. How can I make it work? Or what is the best way to redirect me back?

Comment: It's tied into the form submission. SO in order for it to work you have to submit your form. Or remove the `setTimeOut` from the form submission code. *Assuming I am understanding you correctly*

Comment: once you hit :3000, there is no way to "get back to :8080", FROM a script on :8080. The code on :3000 needs to do the redirect back.. ala: window.location.href = document.referrer;

Comment: You're being redirected before the setTimeout() fires and as andrew3wap says, it's tied into the form submission, so you need to submit the form to trigger the setTimeout, but you're redirected before it can fire.